# Display all posts from selected category

Tags: categories

This is going to be tough to explain. I have created a custom theme and have a file called: categories.php, in this file i have:

```
    <?php
        $args = array('hide_empty' => FALSE);
        wp_list_categories($args);
    ?>
```

This displays all my categories as links, even the ones without a post associated with them.

My permalink structure is this /%category%/%postname%/ so when i click a category name i go to http://example.com/category/action/. This is fine but what i'm struggling with is what file i have to create and what i have to put in said file so it displays all the posts from the clicked category?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if category.php does not exist, make a copy of archive.php or index.php and save it as category.php;

then, before the start of the loop, add:

`<?php global $query_string; query_posts( $query_string . '&posts_per_page=-1'); ?>`

Comment: Why the &posts_per_page=-1, what's the -1 about?

Comment: your question was for 'all posts' and -1 is the parameter to show all posts. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#All_Posts_in_a_Category http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Usage_Note